# Retrieve application path on macos, for both bundles and standalones (C++)

Tags: c++, macos

I need to get the file path of a C++ application on Mac OS Sierra +. The application could be either a .app bundle (in which case I need the path to the bundle and not the inner executable), or could be a standalone executable. Is there a standard C++ way to handle both these cases?

Right now, I observe `CFBundleCopyBundleURL` followed by `CFURLCopyFileSystemPath` gives the correct path for bundles, but the containing directory path for standalones. While `_NSGetExecutablePath` gives the correct path for standalones, but gives the inner executable path for bundles. I use info from both these calls to determine which app type it is, and return its path. My current code for reference:

```
std::string appFilePath;

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef resourcesURL = CFBundleCopyBundleURL(mainBundle);
CFStringRef cfStr = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(resourcesURL, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);
CFRelease(resourcesURL);
char bundlePathStr[PATH_MAX];
CFStringGetCString(cfStr, bundlePathStr, FILENAME_MAX, kCFStringEncodingASCII);
CFRelease(cfStr);
const std::string bundlePath(bundlePathStr);

uint32_t pathBufSize = 0;
_NSGetExecutablePath(NULL, &pathBufSize);
pathBufSize += 1024; // for expansion to abs path
char* appPath = new char[pathBufSize + 1]();
if (_NSGetExecutablePath(appPath, &pathBufSize) == 0 && realpath(std::string(appPath).c_str(), appPath) != NULL)    // alternatively -- if(proc_pidpath(getpid(), topLevelAppPath, pathBufSize) > 0)
{
    const std::string appPathBkp(appPath);
    const std::string appDirPath(dirname(appPath));
    if (appDirPath == bundlePath) // ==> standalone executable
        appFilePath = appPathBkp;
    else // ==> bundled app
        appFilePath = bundlePath;
}
delete[] appPath;

return appFilePath;
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible, both objects are of different kind.